# Do not allow users to cancel Progress Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, block, progressdialog, back-button

In my app if i click outside the progress dialog or if i press on back button, the progress dialog quits before ending the job. How to avoid this behaviour?

Here is the code:

```
private class DownloadDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Instantiate ProgressDialog and Set style to STYLE_HORIZONTAL
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomePage.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setTitle("Downloading");
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // My code
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Update the progress
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // My code
        dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. `Do not allow users to cancel`, yet you explicitly set `dialog.setCancelable(true);`? did you not read the documentation for that method before using it?

Comment: No, it was a copy&paste and i did not mind it. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

in your protected void PreExecute method change this property

```
dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

to

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to disable canceling when the user clicks outside of the view bounds, add this line to your initializer in `onPreExecute`:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change `dialog.setCancelable(true);` to `dialog.setCancelable(false);`